# Disable / Override the Android Back button in Cordova 3.5

Tags: android, cordova

Per the Cordova documentation for version 3.5:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events

I used the following code in an attempt to disable the back button.  The onDeviceReady event fires but the back button event does not.

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
}
```

Amongst other interesting messages I am getting this message in my console:

```
exec() call to unknown plugin App.
```

I've seen several answers to this issue including the following to edit the config.xml file and add this:

```
<feature name="App">
     <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
</feature>
```

None of this is working.

Comment: move the `backbutton` event to the line below the `deviceready` event (not in the callback for `deviceready`, and then make sure you have the `device` plugin installed. also, make sure to add `return false;` at the end of `onBackKeyDown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tipped off by this error:
    exec call to unknown plugin App

I examined the App.java file which holds the App plugin included with the cordova build, I found the following line:

```
protected static final String TAG = "CordovaApp";
```

This did not match the corresponding exec() call made in the cordova.js file which came with 3.5.  So, I changed it to

```
protected static final String TAG = "App";
```

Now the Event overrides for cordova all work per the documentation.

Cheers.

Comment: Isn't that `TAG` constant only used for Logcat logging? Why do you believe this was relevant to your issue?

Comment: Yes, for Android developers, TAG is used as the log tag constant.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the native back button functionality you need to call `preventDefault()` on the event object passed to the handler:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

If you are getting other errors, I'd suggest removing and re-adding the android platform (make sure you have the latest version of Cordova installed first):

```
$ npm update cordova -g
$ cordova platform remove android
$ cordova platform add android
```

It would be best if you could share more of your project, so I can see where something is going wrong. Other checks you can do:

- Ensure you have all plugins installed for any other functionality you might be using `cordova plugin ls` will give you a list of any installed.
- Ensure you reference `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`.
- Check the device ready event is being fired.
- Check there are no JavaScript errors when you debug in Safari dev tools with the app running.

Comment: I did have a call to preventDefault and a return false just for good measure.  However, none of that worked as the event was not firing at all. As far as installing the latest version of cordova, at the time, I had just done a fresh install to bring my version up to 3.5.

Comment: Did you remove and re-add the platform? It would be best if you share more of your project, so I can see where something is going wrong, otherwise I can not help further. I have added some more suggestions to my answer if you have already removed and re-added the platform.

Comment: I neglected to mention that this was a problem which manifested itself during an attempt to control the Android hardware back button.  The issue began with the removal and readdition of the platform.  The onDeviceReady event was firing successfully.  Cordova was functioning correctly in all other aspects.

Comment: spend so much time searching why it doesn't work and turns out that I didn't add cordova.js. Thanks.