# Ionic 2 - How to exit app with back button on Android?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic2

I googled how to make Ionic2 app exit when back button is pressed, however I find totally opposite questions like "How to prevent exiting Ionic2 app when back button pressed?". This is what I want but it keeps switching between the recent tabs when I press back.

I just started the project with `ionic start --v2 myProject tabs` and didn't change anything.

How can I force it to exit whenever back button is pressed on Android devices?

Comment: So you want to override the default native back button and bind it to always exit the app immediately? Or do you mean the back button in the `<ion-header>`?

Comment: because if you want to overwrite the default native back button, check out this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088678/disabel-override-the-android-back-button-in-cordova-3-5

Comment: I want it exit the app immediately

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To exit the app on back button press, you have to register your hardware back button inside your constructor as follows.

```
constructor(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
                navigator['app'].exitApp();                
            });
        });
}
```

But this will be applicable to all the pages. To know more about handling hardware back button check http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: registerBackButtonAction call back is not working in browser. How do I catch backbutton click callback in case of browser

Comment: @Chandru, registerBackButtonAction works only on device.

Comment: @AishApp yes it does. I had to have another solution for browser as in https://gist.github.com/t00ts/3542ac4573ffbc73745641fa269326b8