# exitApp() not working in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to exit the app when the device have no internet connection, but I use exitApp it nothing happened, here is my code:

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private network: Network, public deeplinks: Deeplinks, public events: Events) {
 platform.ready().then(() => {
  let disconnectSub = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('you are offline');
  });

 let connectSub = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(()=> {
    console.log('you are online');
 });

 if(this.network.type === 'none' || this.network.type === 'unknown') {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: "Internet Connection Problem",
    subTitle:"Please Check Your Network connection",
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: () => {
        platform.exitApp();
      }
    }]
  });
  alert.present();
}

});
}
```

Anyone have experience before? Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing that on Android or iOS?

Comment: Yes nothing happened still stay in the app.

Comment: It won't work on iOS since it's against their guidelines. But should work on Android though

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042842/ionic-2-how-to-exit-app-with-back-button-on-android

Comment: Yes i have check this. So iOS have no method to exit app right?

Comment: apparently it is an internal function in platform https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/platform/platform.ts#L385 .. Sry..will remove my answer @Nulra But probably not designed to work in IOS because of the guidelines

Comment: Try `this.platform.exitApp();`

Comment: Hi, suraj, that's ok, thanks for your advise.
hrdkisback, thanks~